# Keras model predicts differently when predicting based on video frame vs. individual snapshot

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm training a binary image classification model in Keras, with the end goal of parsing through entire videos. I have a script that reads in a few snapshots from training videos and lets the model predict on them. I have another script that reads in a video and runs the model through each individual frame and saves the output to a DataFrame. For some reason, even though many of the images that the image prediction script goes through are pulled straight from a video, the video prediction script will predict completely differently, even though the input image is the same. The video prediction script always predicts the same class for every frame, even for frames that were in the training set.

Here are the prediction parts of my scripts:

```
#Image Prediction
        image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(impath), (300, 300))
        if("y" in gray.lower()):
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        else:
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

        prediction = model.predict(image)[0]

        print(prediction)
```

```
#Video Prediction
while success:
        success, frame = self.video.read()
        if(not success):
            break
        image = cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        image = image.astype("float") / 255.0

        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

        prediction = self.model.predict(image)[0]

        if(prediction < .5):
            prediction = 0
        else:
            prediction = 1
        print(prediction)
```

These two scripts preprocess the images identically, there shouldn't be any reason why the predictions would turn out differently. I think it has something to do with the way OpenCV reads in video frames, but I have no idea.

When I print the prediction values during the video prediction, they're all very close to .5, which shouldn't happen very often, because my loss value should be around .4, which means I should be getting way more .9s and .1s than .5s.

I'm open to any and all ideas. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure `video.read()` is outputting the same thing `cv2.imread(...)`? Check the values inside.

Comment: I've checked with type() and np.size, both video.read() and cv2.imread() are return numpy arrays of size 270000 and shape (300, 300, 1) @DanielMöller

Comment: what does `np.array_equal(video_array, image_array)` return?

Comment: But none of these say anything about their "content".

Comment: Using the first frame from the video as the image, it returns True @ksooklall

Comment: @DanielMöller the only way the content would be different would be if the snapshot degrades the quality of the original video content, but even then it should be extremely minimal. I've used imshow to compare the images and they're visually identical.

Comment: They could have different ranges, for instance. One between 0 and 255, the other between 0 and 1. But if you checked with numpy equal, then this is not the problem.

Comment: @CharlesAverill, in the first case of Image Prediction, is `gray.lower()` `y` or `n`? Because if it is `y`, then input would be a grayscale image in Image Prediction case, while it would be a color image in Video Prediction case, which would certainly give different predictions.

Comment: Can you show the output of the two process ?